# Use IRC through an Instant Messenger

Tags: proxy, instant-messaging, irc, gateway

My corporate office has IRC blocked, but not instant messaging (like Google Talk). Is there a service that allows me to communicate with an IRC room through Google Talk or another Instant Messaging service?

What I'm envisioning is a website that allows me to register an IM username and tell it to Instant Message that username whenever a new message is posted in a certain IRC room, and when I send an IM from that username to this service, to post that message in an IRC room. Does this exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried a web-based IRC client?

> With **[Mibbit](http://www.mibbit.com/)**, chatting online
>   is easy, just choose your nickname,
>   pick a channel and press go! You don't
>   need to sign up for an account and you
>   can use it from wherever you are with
>   just a web browser.

Another web-based client is http://webchat.freenode.net/

Comment: This one is ok, but you can no longer use it on freenode

Comment: Just found this. Edit your answer to include: http://webchat.freenode.net/ and it will fully answer my question (I don't have enough rep to edit). This "webchat" client is not java based, and therefor does not use my network connections and therefor allows me to do what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are several Java-Applets which allow connecting to IRC Chats. F.e. [Freenode](http://java.freenode.net/) does provide such a service.

Comment: THis uses my connection instead of acting as a proxy. So it is still blocked.